# Exporting SWT Table data to a Excel spreadsheet

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have a SWT Table on my View with five column.

What I want to do is export the data from that table as an Excel spreadsheet.  I want to followings to happen.

1. The column headers from the Table should appear on the spreadsheet.
2. All data should have a font of my choosing.
3. All spreadsheet cells should have a width of my choosing.
4. All the cell format should be 'text'.

Can someone please point me towards the right direction?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Apache POI to dump TableViewer contents into an Excel workbook with good results.

Here's a sample method that creates an XSSFWorkbook containing the contents of a given TableViewer.  It contains examples of styling cells and autosizing column widths.

Note that I have my column names in an array of Strings called tableColumnNames, as they're used elsewhere in my code and it's convenient to just use that array, but you could farm those from the TableViewer as well.

```
private XSSFWorkbook createWorkbookFromTable(TableViewer table) {
    // create a workbook
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // add a worksheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("My Table Data");

    // shade the background of the header row
    XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
    headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LEMON_CHIFFON.getIndex());
    headerStyle.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    headerStyle.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
    headerStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    // add header row
    Table table = table.getTable();
    TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int cellIndex = 0;
    XSSFRow header = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex++);
    for (TableColumn column : columns) {
        String columnName = column.getText();
        XSSFCell cell = header.createCell(cellIndex++);
        cell.setCellValue(column.getText());
        cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
    }

    // add data rows
    TableItem[] items = table.getTable().getItems();
    for (TableItem item : items) {
        // create a new row
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex++);
        cellIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            // create a new cell
            String columnName = tableColumnNames[i];
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex++);

            // set the horizontal alignment (default to RIGHT)
            XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
            ha = HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
            cellStyle.setAlignment(ha);
            cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);

            // set the cell's value
            String text = item.getText(i);
            cell.setCellValue(text);
        }
    }

    // autofit the columns
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) i);
    }

    return wb;
}
```

Once you've got the XSSFWorkbook, you can dump it to a file like this:

```
public void dumpWorkbookToAFile(XSSFWorkbook wb, String filename) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        MessageDialog.openInformation(shell,
            "Save Workbook Successful",
            "Workbook saved to the file:\n\n" + filename);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        String msg = ioe.getMessage();
        MessageDialog.openError(shell, 
            "Save Workbook Failed",
            "Could not save workbook to the file:\n\n" + msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use OpenOffice SDK to create spreadsheets programmatically. However it must be installed and the service must be running while the user is working with the view. I don't know whether it is acceptable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these frameworks to create an Excel sheet with Java Application, depending on your requirement and complexity of the application.
1. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html
2. http://extentech.com/estore/product_detail.jsp?product_group_id=1